# for each loop exception

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I get an exception in my second print line.

```
int num[] = {50,20,45,82,25,63};
System.out.print("Given number : ");
for(int d:num){
System.out.print("  " + num[d]);
}
```

The console output is

```
Given number : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50
```

Why doesn't d take all the array elements but only 50?

Comment: When you use the foreach syntax: for(int d : num){ // etc  }   d isn't a index it's the value already indexed!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `for(int d:num)` loop every item is represented by `d` not `num[d]`

So, here is how it should be done.

```
for(int d:num){
    System.out.print("  " + d);
}
```

---

A simple dry run will show you where you went wrong.

> For the first loop your statement will come down to **`num[50]`** which is not available anywhere, so you get the exception.

---

However, if your attempt was to use indexing, then a simple trick below will do the trick

```
int index = 0;
for(int d:num){
    System.out.print("  " + num[index++]);
}
```

But I honestly believe, this is **not** the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In for each loop **num[any index]** is not required. It just retrieves from first index to last index and assign each of them to he variable d. So you just need to print the value d.

```
for(int d:num){
System.out.print("  " + d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the enhanced for loop you can use the varable "d" in your example directly:

```
System.out.print(d);
```

The reason you get an ArrayIndexOutOfBound is that `num[d]` tries to acces the 50th place in the array on first iteration. (Which is out of bound).

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to use array index while using for each loop.

In your code,

```
int num[] = {50,20,45,82,25,63};
System.out.print("Given number : ");
for(int d:num)
{
    System.out.print("  " + num[d]);
}
```

in the first iteration will result in `d = 50`, which is your desired result. If you use `num[d]`, it will result in `num[50]`, which is the wrong index.

Instead, use the below code

```
for(int d:num)
{
    System.out.print("  " + d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to code like below.

```
for(int d:num){
System.out.print("  " + d);
}
```

[How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)